# Binary Tree represented using array

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Consider the following array, which is claimed to have represented a binary tree:

[1, 2, 5, 6, -1, 8, 11]

Given that the index with value -1 indicates the root element, I've below questions:

a) How is this actually represented?

Should we follow below formulae ([source from this link](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/311/html/tree-notes.html#heaps)) to figure out the tree?
Three simple formulae allow you to go from the index of the parent to the index of its children and vice versa:

```
* if index(parent) = N, index(left child) = 2*N+1
* if index(parent) = N, index(right child) = 2*N+2
* if index(child) = N, index(parent) = (N-1)/2 (integer division with truncation)
```

If we use above formulae, then index(root) = 3, index(left child) = 7, which doesn't exist.

b) Is it important to know whether it's a complete binary tree or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given an array, you could think of any number of ways how could that array represent a binary tree. So there is no way to know, you have to go to the source of that array (whatever that is).

One of those ways is the way binary heap is usually represented, as per your link. If this was the representation used, -1 would not be the root element. And the node at position 3 would have no children, i.e. it would be a leaf.

And, yeah, it's probably important to know whether it's supposed to be a complete tree or not.

In general, you shouldn't try to figure out what does some data mean like this. You should be given documentation or the source code that uses the data. If you don't have that and you really need to reverse-engineer it, you most likely need to know more about the data. Observing the behavior of the code that uses it should help you. Or decompiling the code.

Answer (score 25):

N=0 must be the root node since by the rules listed, it has no parent.  0 cannot be created from either of the expressions (2*N + 1) or (2*N + 2), assuming no negative N.

Note, index is not the value stored in the array, it is the place in the array.
    For [1, 2, 5, 6, -1, 8, 11]
       Index 0 = 1
       Index 1 = 2
       Index 2 = 5, etc.

If it is a complete tree, then -1 is a valid value and tree is

```
    1  
   /  \  
  2    5  
 / \  / \  
6 -1 8  11
```

-1 could also be a "NULL" pointer, indicating no value exists at that node.

So the Tree would look like

```
    1  
   / \  
  2   5  
 /   / \  
6   8  11
```

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that parent of node at index i can be accessed by looking at index (i-1)/2.

Comment: and for an even `i`, its gotta be floor((i - 1) / 2) a

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a complete binary tree, but it may not be an arbitrary one either. You can represent a tree in which at most a few of the rightmost few leaves are missing (or, if you exchange the convention for left and right children, at most a few of the leftmost leaves missing).

You can't represent this in your array:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 /   / 
D   E
```

But you can represent this

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \  
D   E
```

or this:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
     / \  
    D   E
```

(for the last, have 2k+1 be the *right* child and 2k+2 the *left* child)

You only need to know to number of nodes in the three.